# Microsoft graph api returning NULL in Department field

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have given all required permissions for retrieving user info from Azure active directory like User.Read.All and User.Read but still getting Department and EmployeeId field as NULL

code used:

```
public Microsoft.Graph.User GetUser(ref GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, string UserId)
    {
        return graphServiceClient.Users[UserId].Request().GetAsync().Result;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) both `department` and `employeeId` are returned only on `$select`.

Use `Select` method and specify those two properties. If you need to return more properties, they need to be specified in `Select`. Without using `Select`, Graph API return only default set of properties.

```
public Microsoft.Graph.User GetUser(ref GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, string UserId)
{
    return graphServiceClient.Users[UserId]
             .Request()
             .Select("department,employeeId")
             .GetAsync()
             .Result;
}
```

Resources:

[Select parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#select-parameter)